# Laravel api put-request: why does it work locally, and not on the server?

Tags: laravel, api, http-status-code-405

My app runs fine locally.
I can create and add cards with pictures.

Now I try to deploy the app ( first time I deploy a complete self made application...).
Probably I made a basic mistake. Just cannot figure out what it is...

On the get a 405 error message : The server returned a "405 Method Not Allowed".

The laravel/storage/logs/laravel.log show no errors.

```
     public function store(Request $request)
    {

        //logger($request->all());
        //validate data first
        $request->validate([
            'description'=> 'required'
        ]);

        
        $card = $request->all();
       
        if ($request->hasFile('imagefile')){
        
            $this->validate($request, ['picture' => 'max:2000'], ['Maximum file size of 2MB allowed']);

            $image = $request->file('imagefile'); //file_picture_input  is naam van file inputveld in het formulier, de naam die de request aan de file geeft
           
                $image_name = strval(time().Str::random(5)).$image->getClientOriginalName();
                
            $img = Image::make($image);
            $img->resize(300, 300, function ($constraint) {
                    $constraint->aspectRatio();
                });
                $image->storeAs('images',$image_name,'public');  // store in subdir 'ímages, in disk: 'public' dus storage/app/public/images

                $path = asset('storage/images/'.$image_name);  // omdat storage:link is gedaan, is storage == storage/app/public/
            
                $card['picture'] = $path;
        }
        else {
            $card['picture'] = 'img/profile/default_avatar.png';
        }
    
        //create a post
        return response(Card::create($card),201);
    }
```

This is the vue component method calling the api:

```
        addCard(){
            // de informatie voor de card staat inthis.$card, nu omzetten naar FormData om file toe te voegen aan de request zodat api die kan opslaan, api gaat ook naam bedenken voor de card.
            //  via fetchCards() komt die naam dadelijk terug in card.picture
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('title',this.card.title);
            formData.append('description',this.card.description);
            formData.append('imagefile',this.selectedFile);
            formData.append('speler_id', this.currentSpeler.speler.id);
            formData.append('game_id', this.currentGame.id);
           
           

            if(this.edit === false){  // eerste keer dat kaart wordt getoond is edit ===false, als er dan geen kaart is, wordt er een toegevoegd
                //add
                fetch(`api/cards`, {
                    method: 'post',
                    body:formData,
                    headers:{
                        //'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
                       // 'accept':'application/json'
                    }
                })
                .then(res => console.log(res))
            
                .then(data => {
                    this.card.title='';
                    this.card.description='';
                    this.card.picture='';
                    this.$refs.fileUpload.value=null;
                    this.url='';
                    this.showSpelerCards();
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
            } else{   // als je hier belandt via editCard functie, dan is de editCard ===true, en kom je hier terecht
                //update
                fetch(`api/cards/${this.card.id}?_method=PUT`, {
                    method: 'post',
                    body:formData,
                    headers:{
                       // 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
                        //'accept':'application/json'
                    }
                })
                //.then(res => res.formData())
                .then(res => console.log(res))
                .then(data => {
                    this.card.title='';
                    this.card.description='';
                   // alert('Card updated');
                   this.url='';
                    this.$refs.fileUpload.value=null;
                    this.showSpelerCards();
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
            }
        },
```

The route is:

```
 Route::apiResource('/cards', 'App\Http\Controllers\CardController');
```

Locally everything works fine, on the VPS it fails. So I do not make a fundamental error...

Can any one see what might be the problem?

Comment: What route and method combination is causing this error? Does it exist in the routes table?

Comment: The addcard method in the cardcontroller store method causes the error. Defined by standard apiResource route is the culprit I think. Locally it works, so route is valid I would think...

Comment: Can you open up your browser developer tools and look at the network requests? Is there a redirect happening? For example, an `http` to `https` redirect?

Comment: I see no redirects. This is the header in response `Request URL: http://xxx.xxx/api/cards/1?_method=PUT
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed
Remote Address: 185..xxxx.xx.xx
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
allow: GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Wed, 29 Dec 2021 09:35:45 GMT
Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
Transfer-Encoding: chunked`